# Sticky session with application cookie on AWS ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have an application with multiple EC2 instances behind an ELB. Previously, we enabled sticky session on ELB using AWSELB cookie (AWS generated cookie strategy) and it was working smoothly.

Now, due to some requirement, we have to use application cookie to set up sticky session on ELB.

In the request we are sending this application generated cookie but it is not working.

Can anyone please assist me?

Comment: What specifically isn't working? You need to specify exactly what your problem is. If the browser is sending the specified cookie to the load balancer on multiple requests, and that cookie's value is the same for each of those requests, then each request should be routed to a single EC2 instance.

Comment: Can you please let me know when I am using application cookie for sticky session then why AWS generate it's own AWSELB cookie.

Comment: Who cares if it generates its own cookie? All that matters is what cookie it is using for session tracking.

Comment: In my application I have an ELB on front end server and also an ELB on Backend server. In front end I am using application cookie based session affinity and in the backend I am using AWSELB generated session affinity . But the issue over here is AWSELB cookie is generated by both ELB .Now my backend AWSELB cookie is overridden by the frontend generated cookie.So I am not able to acheive session affinity in the Backend code

Comment: OK, how does that extra info you just added in your comment affect anything at all? What is the actual issue you are experiencing here? Again I ask: What **specifically** isn't working?

Comment: Since the request pass from one ELB to another ,so AWSELB get's overidden.

Comment: @MarkB do you have any idea. I have edited the above comment .